# Why Earth's orbit is elliptical though gravity makes body rotate in circular orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

As we know that gravitation makes a body rotate in circle 
So sun should also make earth rotate in circular orbit
But why earth rotates in elliptical 
We not think that it is to cover equal areas in equal time
My question is why it became elliptical at first defying gravitational law (at formation of orbit)

Comment: Bodies do not rotate in circular orbits as even the smallest disturbance will result result in an elliptical orbit.  You can think of the circle as a very special type of ellipse with box axes exactly the same size.

Comment: Re, "...gravitation makes a body rotate..." That is not true.  Gravitation attracts bodies directly toward one another.  It is the interacting laws of gravity and inertia that _allow_ (not cause) bodies to orbit one another.

Comment: But if a disturbance causes changes then the after sometime gravity will again make that to rotate in circular orbit like we rotate a stone by attaching it to a string but why the distance will vary ie somewher it is more and at some place less

Comment: If we place a ball in a water tub and rotate then the ball makes near particles to come to it that is what called gravity then the particles ultimately attach to the ball but what if the particles has some rotation on their own causing centrifugal force outward then they will start to rotate this is gravity which comes into act due to rotational motion of a body as einstein said

Comment: No, this is complete nonsense, and Einstein most certainly has never said anything of that sort. The experiment you quote has nothing to do with gravitational attraction. And, no, it is not the case that "gravitation makes a body rotate in circle".

Comment: Just not say by ur own please search the books or can do that on net which will tell u that einstein told that gravitation is due to rotation and if u say that einstein did not said it or it is nonsense then canu say that as EVERY FORCE IS ATTRACTIVE OR REPULSIVE BUT WHY GRAVITATIONAL FORCE IS ATTRACTIVE ALWAYS that is what matters

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why it became elliptical at first defying gravitational law(at formationof orbit)

The gravitational law is more general than you think, not a circle but an ellipse is the more general stable orbit solution.

In general the solution of the orbits of two bodies in the gravitational well of each other are [conic sections](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Math/consec.html)

> One application is that a moving particle that is subjected to an inverse square law force like gravity or Coulomb's law will follow a path described by one of the conic sections.

[parabolas,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section) hyperbolas, ellipses ( of which limiting cases are circles and lines)

One of the two bodies is sitting at a focus of the ellipse (an ellipse becomes circle when the two foci fall on each other) . Parabolas and hyperbolas are scatteringsaround a focus leaving off to infinity. In a line ( the limit when the  two ellipse foci are very far from each other) one object falls on the other.

[image: conic sections]

The "why"s answered  by " because when [the disk  that coalesced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formation_and_evolution_of_the_Solar_System) into the mass that became the earth was formed it happened that the sun  was close to one of the two ellipse foci."

> The formation of the Solar System began 4.6 billion years ago with the gravitational collapse of a small part of a giant molecular cloud.Most of the collapsing mass collected in the center, forming the Sun, while the rest flattened into a protoplanetary disk out of which the planets, moons, asteroids, and other small solar system    bodies formed.

Comment: Cant understand

Comment: did you look at the link?

Comment: i have edited extensively

Comment: Madam anna me would be happy if u would tell me that why (not mathematically)but from physical point of view if i have thrown a particle away i meant it starts rotating on basis of gravitation then how can it go farther distance at sometime and come nearer at other and that dont happen when moon revolves around earth

Comment: because the earth is sitting in one of the focuses of the elipse. It does happen with the moon https://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/~barnes/ASTR110L_S03/lunarorbit.html . Maybe this about satellites will help you http://www.physicsclassroom.com/mmedia/vectors/sat.cfm

Comment: Yes the satellite one when released does revolves in circular like that during big bang earth should have moved in circular but why it goes somewhere more distance and somewhere less please do think practically when the gravitational force is same then how can that same force make body come nearer at some and farther at some

Comment: That is why mathematics is used, it balances the forces that just thinking about them does not seem obvious. look at this angular momentum conservation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLdlfWT7UN0 video

Comment: Yes thats correct maths balances forces but madam try to understand my point    it can be given theoritically but not practically ,i meant we have a reason on pen and paper but what about what happens there ,imeant in practical situation because angular momentum is like a pseudo theory

Comment: look, this is a physics site and questions are answered with mathematics relative to physics, not handwavings. You  are  asking in the wrong site for that. Had you ever ridden a bicycle  you would know about angular momentum first hand and whether it is pseud or not.

Comment: I not know to look and me didnot expected this answer from a retired particle physicist because we all are taking mathematical abstract definitions and not .we read physics but we dont think that physically(reference to feynman lectures) we are only saying that this and this like bicycle and all can u basically say that how in this earth the angular momentum (supposed to be definition of angular force)can act in a direction i.e.perpendicular though there is no action done in that direction . Can u get changes i.e.how u make in linear momentum (work being done) by the angular momentum, no u can

Comment: I am not in this to get badges or anything all i want is just practical approach to my question

Comment: What happened miss/mrs mathematical  iguess u should have been in maths just learning the old blabbers and not thibking practically some new